# Excel sort does not sort numeric values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have three excel columns, each of them contain numeric value (the third column is also the sum of the two columns left), but the excel sort does not seem to recognize that these values are numeric (see screenshot). I can only sort the columns A-Z, which also does not seem to work: The content is not sorted by any means.

What options do I have to fix this?

[image]

Comment: It seems some of the cells contain text, the others numbers. Try to insert a new column with the formula `=C3*1` and sort that column. Does it work?

Comment: other issue can be the empty row, Excel may not consider the whole of your range to belong to the autofilter. Opening the autofilter, do you see all the possible values to filter for them?

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Nope that did not work, exactly same issue as before, also in the autofilter I do not see ANY of the possible values to filter! Just one box: Select all...

Comment: I think I have found the solution: I have to delete Row 2  ...

Comment: Great! maybe you could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert autofilter in an Excel sheet, Excel thinks you want to filter the current range only.

In your example it's only the first row.

To let Excel know your range you can either:

- make sure your range doesn't contain empty rows
- select your whole data range before inserting autofilter.